# MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI does not scan inside data folder

Tags: android, android-storage

I'm fetching music files from device using MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ..
For other folders it is working fine. but it is not fetch/scan music files inside app's data folder (getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath())... why? is there any limitations??? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

> why?

The `MediaStore` has no access to those files, nor does it know about them. Those files are private to  your app.

Comment: can all music files be retrieved by any other method instead of MediaStore?  @CommonsWare

Comment: @Maddy007: Neither you nor `MediaStore` can access files on internal storage of other apps. For your *own* media on internal storage, using `java.io.File`, sweeping through your candidate files and finding those that appear to be music files. You can then combine that with the results of querying `MediaStore` (for media *outside* your app).

Comment: can you tell me getting list of albums using MediaStore. I have used below code

String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;

String[] projections = new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART};

contentResolver.query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projections, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

What should I do if I want to get list of albums from specific folder only?